# Tab in bash autocompletes from path, how can I extend it to also autocomplete from .bash_history?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, command-line-arguments

I love path autocompletion, but one thing I miss is that if the last time I used a command was with a long set of arguments, and I want to repeat that (without writing a script), I can't type

`>command arg1 arg2_prefix` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

And <kbd>Tab</kbd> through a list of the last times I did this.

Some commands ship with autocompletion, but others don't, and I'd like this "history autcomplete" to be searched before path autocomplete when I'm within the arguments of a command.

I haven't through this through very much, but it seems useful. My question is how I can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and more convenient solution is just hitting ctrl-R inside your terminal and start typing the command, it'll start filtering from your history list (i.e: with arguments as well).